# Understanding the value of standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have two datasets $\{10,10,2,2\}$ and $\{13,7,0,4\}$. Now, when I compute standard deviation for both the sets, I get $4$ and $4.74$ respectively. My question: what is the significance of $4.74$ or $4$? I understand the basic definition of standard deviation i.e. deviation from the mean etc; but how to understand the value $4.74$?

Comment: You can think of it as how "spread out" the values are.  For somewhat extreme example, the data sets $\{1,1,1,2,3,3,3\}$ and $\{-5,-2,1,2,3,6,9\}$ both have the same mean but each have low and high standard deviation respectively relatively speaking.  The "closer together" the data, the smaller the standard deviation while the "more spread out" it is the larger the standard deviation.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I understand lower the sigma value, data are less dispersed; but what I am asking is, What is the importance of the actual value (4.74 in above case)?  Just to give an example mean value of the set {10, 10, 2,2} is 6 which means if you are trying to predict the sequence, predicting it to the mean value will give you least error. I want to know something of this kind.

Comment: As opposed to the answer relating to normally distributed data, a more general inequality would be https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality which is always applicable.  The specific value relates as already mentioned to how spread out the data is (or worded a different way, how close they all are to the mean).

Comment: @JMoravitz: Wow! this is lovely. This is just what I was expecting. However wikipedia says, in 8th line **under Chebyshev's inequality a minimum of just 75% of values must lie within two standard deviations of the mean and 89% within three standard deviations**. Don't you think it should be **.....75% of values will lie....** instead  of **......75% of values must lie.......**?

Comment: I see no difference between the two phrasings "*will lie*" versus "*must lie*".  They both imply that regardless how the data is distributed with absolute certainty a minimum of 75% of values are within two standard deviations of the mean.

Comment: I feel having "_must lie_" makes it  look like a condition, only then Chebyshev's inequality is valid or can be applied. Don't you think?

Comment: That is not the desired interpretation anyways.  The hypothesis is that $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  The conclusion is chebyshev's inequality.  How the data is distributed is irrelevant to the hypothesis.  Thinking of it as an if-then clause, "75% of values..." will be a part of the *then* section, not a part of the *if* section.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the sequence has a normal distribution, with mean value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then the probability of getting a sample in the interval $\left[\mu-\sigma, \mu+\sigma\right]$ will be roughly equal to [68.27%](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

So when you have measured something, which has a normal distribution, for a finite time and calculate the mean and standard deviation, then you can use that to make a prediction for future measurements.

In order to test whether a sequence has a normal distribution you can look at its skewness $\nu$ and kurtosis $\kappa$. The skewness tells you something about how asymmetric the distribution is, while the kurtosis tells you something about how likely it is to have outliers which lie far away from the mean relative to the standard deviation. In the literature there multiple expressions for these, but I will give you one which is used in the statistical software Statgraphics,

$$
\nu = \frac{1}{(n-1)\sigma^3} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^3,
$$

$$
\kappa = \frac{1}{(n-1)\sigma^4} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^4.
$$

When the absolute value of $\nu$ is bigger than 2 then that is an indication that the distribution has a significant deviation from Gaussian. For a normal distribution the value of $\kappa$ is 3, for larger values then the distribution is more outlier-prone and for smaller values then the distribution is less outlier-prone.

Comment: I thought I have almost understood the importance of sigma value (4.74 in my example) when it is said 68.27% of the values lies in between [u-sigma, u+sigma]. However, first line says **"If you assume sequence has a normal distribution"**, are there any conditions to call the sequence as normally distributed?

Comment: @NareshR See the edit of my answer, about skewness.

Comment: This is getting more and more interesting than I thought. Let's say I have solved for **v** and it is <2, then I presume I can apply **68.27.......rule**, but what if  **v** turns out to be >2, there should be some importance of **sigma** like the one you talked earlier (68.27% rule), What do you say?